# MySQL grant function not working properly MySQL WorkBench 8.0

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-workbench, sakila-database

I defined grants for the user John :

```
grant select on * to JOHN@localhost;
```

and upon running:

```
show grants for JOHN@localhost;
```

I get :

```
GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO `JOHN`@`localhost`
```

But when I try to remove the grant from a specific table, actor:

```
revoke select on sakila.actor from JOHN@localhost;
```

it says:

> Error Code: 1147. There is no such grant defined for user 'JOHN' on
> host 'localhost' on table 'actor'

What could have gone wrong?

I tried to give select grants separately on `sakila.*` but still it won't identify that John has grants over actor table.
Only when I explicitly `grant select to JOHN for sakila.actor`, it identifies it.

Answer (score 0):

Because, there is no specific grant given to the user `JOHN@localhost` on the table `sakila.actor`.  The permission given is on `*` - i.e. all DBs, all tables.

Think about what this REVOKE will have to do, if it is supported.

It will have to subtract `sakila.actor` from `*.*`.
That means, MySQL will have to add ALL the different `DB.*` grants for that user, and then for all the tables of `sakila`, except `actor`.

That MySQL cannot do.

MySQL will only revoke the permissions that are explicitly given.

If the permissions are given on `*.*` only those permissions can be revoked.

If you give explicit permission on `sakila.actor`, then only that can be revoked. If you give explicit permission on `sakila.*`, then only that can be revoked, and so on...

If you give permission on `sakila.*` or `*.*` and then try to revoke permissions from only a sub-set of those, MySQL won't do that, as if it does, it would have to actually assume permissions on everything else.